# ASP.NET Wizard - Hiding SideBar Entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspwizard

I'm using an ASP.NET wizard control with a sidebar for navigation. I've got around ten wizard steps and they all appear in the sidebar but there are a few of them which I don't want to appear in the sidebar.

Can anyone suggest how to prevent specific wizard steps from being represented in the sidebar?

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: you are always welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.displaysidebar.aspx

Here is the referance code:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="wz1" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false">
```

Or

Use Jquery to hide and show it.

Functions : `.hide()` , `.show()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not trying to hide the sidebar completely. I'm only trying to prevent some of the steps being displayed in the sidebar - some steps should be shown, others should not.

Comment: @user2025399 you can use jquery for this purpose, see my edit